# Data Binding for alternative layouts

Tags: android, android-databinding

I have faced with an issue with data binding for different layouts.
I have layout file for different orientation.
For portrait mode:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

and for landspace mode:

```
<layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/extra_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
</layout>
```

And when I use it for binding via

```
ViewBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.setContentView(this, R.layout.view);
```

I have no access for `extraContainer` from current binding.

Possible solution to add the view with same id and check the view class in runtime. Any other solutions ?

Comment: can you show me your layout structure?

Comment: `res/layout/view.xml` and `res/layout-sw600dp-land/view.xml`

Comment: I can't see any error for this. Don't know why this is not working.

Comment: I don't think so anything is wrong with your code, try it with *clean and rebuild.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was fixed by updating Gradle version to 2.1.0, but there are no mentions on Gradle Revision and I dont know how it was related to Gradle version.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have solution for `DataBinding` with different configuration. But I have suggestion like, remove that "tablet" layout from `res/layout-sw600dp-land/view.xml` and merge it with default view.

Check with orientation and initialize `extra_container` layout in landscape mode else hide it and don't initialize.

Comment: It is not a solution, because most of the time you need different xml layout files for tablet and phone, that sub views are arranged completely different, or not exist at all.