# Android data binding with landscape layout

Tags: android, android-layout, android-databinding

I create layout for portrait and landscape orientation (layout,layout-land).

Layout portrait:

```
<layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

<data>

    <variable
        name="selectedPage"
        type="java.lang.Integer" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout >...
```

And layout landscape:

```
 <layout xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <data>

<variable
    name="selectedPage"
    type="java.lang.Integer" />

</data>

<RelativeLayout >...
```

I'm trying to call method binding.getSelectedPage(), but getting error:

Error:(113, 28) error: cannot find symbol method getSelectedPage()

The error is occurred  even if I just copy the portrait layout file to the layout-land directory.

How to solve such a problem?

Comment: first you need set the values for getSelectedPage then only you can get the values getSelectedPage()., post your code ellobrately

Comment: have you referred [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36862494/data-binding-for-alternative-layouts)?

Comment: have you figured out the solution? I'm facing the same problem

Answer (score 0):

Your question got nothing with databinding or layout orientation. There's simply no `getSelectedPage()` method in `java.lang.Integer` class.

You may want to read [docs](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html), spec. "Variables" chapter, paying also attention to "Imports"

Comment: When I removed landscape layout file, everything works fine

Comment: Since there's no difference in both layout snippet you posted, I suspect this is still not the culprit

Comment: The error is occurred even if I just copy the portrait layout file to the layout-land directory.

Answer (score 0):

It's a weird behavior in the source creator, maybe a bug. I had a look into it before. For some reason the binding class doesn't contain the getter like [documented](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding/index.html#variables):

> The generated binding class will have a setter and getter for each of the described variables. The variables will take the default Java values until the setter is called — `null` for reference types, `0` for `int`, `false` for `boolean`, etc.